# Semaphores secure shell C

Tags: c, process, semaphore, selectionchanging

Hey Guys what I have recently started and I am not very good at using semaphores. What I am trying to do is have one process display a number (e.g. 1) and the other process display 2 and then switch back to to the first process display 3 and then back to the second process display 4 and so on.... At the moment I was able to display 1 then 2 then 3 but unfortunately it goes back to 1 instead of displaying 4.How do I make it display 4 . Please help :)

```
//critical.c
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "se_sems.h"

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    const int ONE_DONE = 0;
    const int TWO_DONE = 1;
    volatile int flag = ONE_DONE;


    //Use our source file as the "key"
    int id = se_semget("critical.c",1);

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid) {
        //P1
        while(1) {
            flag = ONE_DONE;

            se_wait(id);
            printf("2222222222 \n");
            printf("22222222222 \n");
            fflush(stdout);
            se_signal(id);

            flag = TWO_DONE;
            do {
                sleep(1);
            } while (flag == ONE_DONE);
            printf("444444444444 \n");
            printf("44444444444 \n");

            se_signal(id);
        }
    } else {
        //P2
        while (1) {
            flag = TWO_DONE;
            se_wait(id);
            printf("1111111 \n");
            printf("1111111 \n");
            fflush(stdout);
            se_signal(id);

            flag = ONE_DONE;
            do {
               sleep(1);
            } while (flag == TWO_DONE);
            printf("33333333 \n");
            printf("3333333333 \n");
            se_signal(id);
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
1111111
1111111
2222222222
22222222222
33333333
3333333333
1111111
1111111
444444444444
44444444444
2222222222
22222222222
33333333
3333333333
1111111
1111111
444444444444
44444444444
```

and so on :)

Comment: Is this **C++** or **C**? Because the first comment in the file you posted suggests it is **C**. Also fixing the indentation will help people to help you.

Comment: Are you using `flag` as a method of communication after the fork?

Comment: Oh yes thank you it is C not C++

Comment: Any ideas it took me ages to figure this out now got to go a step further

Comment: First, you should use 2 semaphores.  Second, your `flag` is useless since forking causes each process to have its own flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to do it is to leave the last display empty therefore it will look as if it displays it in order. So no you don't need 2 semaphores.